# CODEIGNITER 3 : Page not found, cannot reach controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I have a problem with my codeigniter 3 application. The application folder is in a subfolder nammed "grease" : /grease/application/...

The base_url is like that : https://< url >/grease/

I tried to go to this page for example : https://< url >/grease/Auth, I got an error "Page not found, The page you requested could not be found"

My controller name and classe name starts with capital letter

The .htaccess file looks like that :

```
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch 
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt|piwik/|crontab/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
php_value post_max_size 300M
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
```

Can you help me ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running in a sub-folder than you need to add ***RewriteBase*** directive in your ***.htaccess*** file.

```
RewriteBase /YOUR-SUBFOLDER
```

Comment: Thanks fort your answer.
But I have an error : "Internal Server Error, the server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request"